# Very strange horizontal lines in plt graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a following code that plots three lines into one graph in matplotlib:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as plt



df = pd.read_csv("balici_naskladnovaci.csv")

df = df.sort_values(by = "interval start")
df["interval start"] = pd.to_datetime(df["interval start"])

# balici
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(
    df[df["expedice"] == "liberec"]["interval start"].astype(str),
    df[df["expedice"] == "liberec"]["balici"],
    color="red",
    label="Liberec",
)

ax.plot(
    df[df["expedice"] == "jablonec"]["interval start"].astype(str),
    df[df["expedice"] == "jablonec"]["balici"],
    color="blue",
    label="Jablonec",
)

ax.plot(
    df[df["expedice"] == "lipa"]["interval start"].astype(str),
    df[df["expedice"] == "lipa"]["balici"],
    color="green",
    label="Lípa",
)

ax.set_ylabel("Počet baličů", color="black", fontsize=14)


plt.title("Balici napric expedicemi")
plt.tight_layout()
fig.legend()
plt.show()
```

But the result is very strange, because of these horizontal lines:

[image]

Do you know, how can I fix it please?

Comment: Why do you have the x-axis as a string even though you are converting to date format? astype(str) is not needed.

Comment: There is likely some unsorted data. Matplotlib will plot the data in the order it is stored in the array/series/dataframe.

Comment: You may want to first perform your three selections, then sort each selection on "interval start", before plotting.

Comment: @9769953 I tried `df = df.sort_values(by = "interval start")` but it did not work. Making three selection did not help

Comment: Is the data (publicly) available? The (very) few times I've run into similar plots, there was something obvious in the data that explained it.

Comment: @9769953 no, only private data. But this is really strange, it works when I plot only one line perfectly. But it fails like this on multiple graphs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matplotlib plotting additional lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62744119/matplotlib-plotting-additional-lines)

Comment: @JodyKlymak unfortunately no, because suggested solution by `np.argsort` is not suitable for panel data. I would have to split my df before, which is complicated way. My answer below using seaborn seem to be more suitable.

Comment: The particular magic wand is not the point - the point is you need to  sort the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my own solution, `seaborn` seems to be much more efficient in this type of data:

```py
ax = plt.axes()

sns.lineplot(x ='interval start', y = 'balici', hue='expedice',  data=df)


for tick in ax.get_xticklabels():
    tick.set_rotation(90)

for index, label in enumerate(ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()):
    label.set_visible(False)
    if index % 10 == 0:
        label.set_visible(True)

plt.title("Balici napric expedicemi")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Indeed, Seaborn was more or less made for these kind of data(set) visualisations.